# while converting java String which is having Big Decimal in json object form to JSONObject the value of big decimal is getting changed

Tags: java, json

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"BigdecimalValue\",\"value\":28.074890126710765}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
//expected value=28.074890126710765, actual value=28.074890126710766
    }
}
```

[image]
i have decimal value stored in java string in form of json object, when i convert string to JSONObject then the value of decimal is getting changed.please look into the code snippet and output.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the actual code and actual error message in text.  What is your question? Is it why the value changes? Please be explicit.

Comment: `BigDecimal bigdecimal = jsonObject.getJsonNumber("value").bigDecimalValue();` should work. I face same problem from 2.4 use json-lib 2.3

Comment: i have one java string variable which contains the json structure like this({"name":"bigDecimalValue","value":28.074890126710765}), now i want to convert this java string to JSONObject or JSONNode..but when i do so then after converting to JSONObject the value of decimal is getting changed..i want the exact JSONObject like i passed as String  -- @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: if i pass java string like this.. String jsonString = "{\"value\":28.074890126710765}"; i should get the json object(org.json.JSONObject) without changing the value. i do not know why value is getting chnaged if i do like this JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"value\":28.074890126710765}");..now if i check the decimal value it comes as 28.074890126710766 instead of 28.074890126710765 --@Eklavya

Comment: this is my code..
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Sample {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
  String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"BigdecimalValue\",\"value\":28.074890126710765}";
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
  System.out.println(jsonObject);
 }
}  -- @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class MyClass{
    public BigDecimal value;
}
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException {
        String jsonStr = "{\"value\":27.010203040506070805}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyClass myObj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyClass.class);
        System.out.print(myObj.value);
    }
}
```

Here is the output

> Test.main()$ 27.010203040506070805

Comment: actually what i want here is after converting from string object to json object value of big decimal should not change

Comment: please convert that java String object to json object without changing the decimal value..i want the json object similar to the string i passed in jsonstr